# Animating polylines Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

How would I got about animating a series of polylines in Google Maps?

My only idea was to possibly have many points along a path and time each draw from only polyline to another. This however does not seem feasible.

Comment: What is your question?  What do you mean by "animating a series of polylines"?  [animated marker on polyline from directions service](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html) - [animate marker on polyline from xml](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_xml.html) - [add animated symbols to a polyline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644427/multiple-polyline-to-a-marker-on-google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800865/animate-google-maps-polyline